# Audio tracks while merging multiple videos using FFMPEG in Android?

Tags: android, c++, video, ffmpeg, javacv

I have problem in video processing in Android.

To merging multiple videos, I'm now using ffmpeg c++ library and JavaCV.

Here is my code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    String firstVideo = params[0];
    String secondVideo = params[1];
    String outPutVideo = params[2];

    try {
        FrameGrabber grabber1 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(firstVideo);
        grabber1.start();
        FrameGrabber grabber2 = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(secondVideo);
        grabber2.start();
        FrameRecorder recorder2 = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(outPutVideo, grabber2.getImageWidth(),
                grabber2.getImageHeight(), grabber1.getAudioChannels());

        recorder2.setVideoCodec(grabber2.getVideoCodec());
        recorder2.setFrameRate(grabber2.getFrameRate());
        recorder2.setSampleFormat(grabber2.getSampleFormat());
        recorder2.setSampleRate(grabber2.getSampleRate());
        recorder2.setAudioChannels(2);
        recorder2.start();
        Frame frame;
        int j = 0;

        while ((frame = grabber1.grabFrame()) != null) {
            j++;
            recorder2.record(frame);
        }
        while ((frame = grabber2.grabFrame()) != null) {
            recorder2.record(frame);
        }
        recorder2.stop();
        grabber2.stop();
        grabber1.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        success = false;
    }
    return null;
}
```

First video has no sound, and second video has audio tack.

Audio of second video starts from start of result video.

I tried and had search many hours, but cannot find solution. Please give me advise if you have experience!!!